# Ctrl+Z (SIGTSTP) has strange behavior in bash shell in docker container

Tags: bash, powershell, docker

I am using Docker for Desktop on Windows. I start a container with a bash shell in Powershell like this:
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
Inside the bash shell I can send INT signals with Ctrl+C as expected, but Ctrl+Z/SIGTSTP has unexpected behavior.
For a while it would always exit the bash process and return me to the Powershell even when I was in a child process like vim.
Other times it will freeze bash and not take any more input.
I've tried to use bash trap to see if the signal is caught but it doesn't seem to be the case. What is likely happening here? I can't tell if the problem is with bash, the container, or Powershell.

Comment: For some strange reason you can fix it by switching to legacy mode. Open Powershell, right click on top bar, properties, options, tick legacy mode and restart. I have no idea why this works, but it is the best I could find.

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7811) is still unsolve.

I am using ConEmu and some setting instead of powershell to avoid this strange behavior.
(For all aspect, ConEmu is more powerfull than the powershell or legacy mode.)

The settings is following:

```
hotkey : macro
ctrl+z : MsgBox("ctrl+z is disabled. To avoid strange behavior of docker on powershell.","trapped ctrl+z")
```

This intercepts ctrl+z and show message box.

ref.

1. https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html
2. https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#MsgBox

Comment: Additional:  win+alt+p (settings) -> keys&macro ->Select Any Macro Type (example Macro12)->Choose hotkey Ctrl+z (set Z char and select Ctrl)-> enter text  in GUIMacro  field- MsgBox("my text")->  Save

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9N0DX20HK701) installed, then in the settings set the hotkey CTRL+Z to any functionality convenient for you.
In this case, stop exit from the container.

(Added)

Preferred way :
run `wsl`
or
run  template command `wsl docker exec -it test bash`

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers